# Testing difference of means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

We are comparing the performance of two type of cars, Renault and Chevrolet cars. We know that $\bar{X_R} = 16.9$ with $s_R=1.3$ and $\bar{X_C}=14$ with $s_C=1.5$. We need to test at $\alpha=0.03$ significance level whether Renault performance is 20% superior than Chevrolet cars.

I´m having trouble stating the test hypothesis. My options are:

a. $H_0: \mu_R - \mu_C \leq 2.8$ vs $H_a: \mu_R - \mu_C > 2.8$

b. $H_0: \mu_R - \mu_C = 0$ vs $H_a: \mu_R - \mu_C > 0$

Comment: Your use of $2.8$ in the hypothesis seems to have been based on what you observe in the sample - that $\bar{x}_C=14$. This would be an error; the hypothesis should relate to population quantities, not sample quantities.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic blunder in experimental design.

When you *design* a study, you need to find a reasonable sample size to provide good power. To do this, you make some assumptions about what the truth might be, such as what you provided above. Indeed, 16.8 = 1.2 * 14, i.e. Renault has 20% of whatever X is compared to Chevy.

There is a difference, therefore, between the specific assumptions of the design, and the formal statement of the hypothesis. The setup of classical null hypothesis testing is not so specific as to tell you *how much different from the null* the alternative hypothesis is - without some very specialized or Bayesian methods.

The specific test is whether Renault and Chevy are equal, and the hypothesis is stated accordingly:

$$
\begin{array}{c} \mathcal{H}_0 : \mu_R = \mu_C \\
\mathcal{H}_1 : \mu_R \ne \mu_C \\ 
\end{array}
$$

For a two-tailed test, or swap the appropriate operators for a one tailed test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had a massive confusion